# UIScrollView clipsToBounds issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

Hello I have a problem with `UIScrollView` and I hope someone can help me.

I have a `UIView` with 700x580 pixel in the center of that view I add a `UIScrollview` with 350x580 pixel. In this `scrollView` I add 10 `subViews` next to each other then I set the property `clipsToBounds` on the `scrollview` to `NO` that I can see the `subViews` of the `scrollView` witch was not in the `scrollView`. Now my problem the `subviews` of the `scrollView` was also show at the outside of the `UIView`. Is there any why to disable that?

Here is a sample code of my problem

```
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 700, 580)];
CGFloat viewDisdance = 50;
UIScrollView *theScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] 
                               initWithFrame:CGRectMake((myView.frame.size.width-350)/2, // X
                                                        0,                               // Y
                                                        350+viewDisdance,                // with
                                                        580)];                           // height

theScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
theScrollView.clipsToBounds = NO;
theScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
[myView addSubview:theScrollView];

CGFloat offset = 0.0;
for (NSInteger i = 0; i<10; i++) {
    UIView *aSubView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(offset, 0, 350, 580)];
    aSubView.backgroundColor = [self randomColor];   //a method that givs me a random color back
    offset += aSubView.frame.size.width;
    offset += viewDisdance;
    [theScrollView addSubview:aSubView];
}

[window addSubview:myView];
```

Here is a screen from the result of this code sample

[image]
http://img18.imageshack.us/i/bildschirmfoto20110104u.png/

the red area is `myView`

the blue area is `theScrollView`

and the other color areas are the `subViews` of `theScrollView`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try `myView.clipsToBounds = YES;`?

Comment: thanks that works that option i had try but i had an enhaced View behind the scrollView that i can scroll outside of the scroll view and now i have add the enhance view as subview to myview and set myview.clipsToBounds = Yes and it works

Comment: That's great! I see you're new here. You should click on the check mark on the left to let other people know which solution solved your problem. Good luck to your project. :)